# Django: assigning a foreignKey object a value of current user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to override the `save()` method in the admin so when my publisher-users are creating their customer-users, the publisher field is automatically assigned a value of current user.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "User: foo": "SimpleSubscriber.publisher" must be a "Publisher" instance.
```

I used this tutorial to get started: [here.](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/)

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not change:
        obj.publisher = request.user
    obj.save()
```

this is the save method override.  The only users who can access the admin are publishers, and both the Publisher and SimpleSubscriber models are user models:

```
class Publisher(User):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

class SimpleSubscriber(User):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = USStateField()
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date_created = models.DateField(null=True)
    sub_type = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    sub_startdate = models.DateField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.last_name
```

What can I replace `request.user` with in order to assign each new SimpleSubscriber to the current publisher user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace `request.user` with an instance of `Publisher`.

One way to do that would be:

```
Publisher.objects.get(**{Publisher._meta.get_ancestor_link(User).name: request.user})
```

Of course, that will do a lookup every time you invoke it, so you might like to design your application to do this on every request.

Another way to do this is to (slightly) abuse the django model system - where one model inherits from another, the corresponding parent and child model instances have the same `id` (by default);

```
Publisher.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
```

Comment: The second suggestion worked. The first one returned an error saying 'User' is not defined.  But I'm very curious about the first suggestion because I do not fully understand the purpose of the ** and I couldn't find any documentation on _meta either.  Where can I learn more about accessing this meta information and using it?

Comment: The first one will only have the error you described because you did not import `User` first.  `**` syntax exists to expand dictionaries to provide keyword arguments: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls ; `_meta` is part of the django internals see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/ and also you can look at the source code, and explore the contents using `dir` (look it up in the standard library reference).